# Can rdd.map function in Spark have no return in specific condition?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, spark-graphx

I have the code below

```
val c: RDD[(String, String)] = graph.triplets.map(
        triplet => {
            if (triplet.attr == "condition"){
                (triplet.srcAttr, triplet.dstAttr)
            }               
        }
    )
```

This throws `type mismatch` error

```
[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: (String, String)
[error]                 if (triplet.attr == "condition"){
[error]                 ^
```

I search for this error and there are some answers saying that this `if` expression requires a `else` following it otherwise the compiler does not know the explicit return of the `map` function

However, I am really confused because that I can use kinds of code below and there is no problem

```
someRDD.map({           
        case (str, cnt) => (cnt)
    })
```

But this one still has no explicit return and it performs really similar like the above wrong one, isn't it?

Comment: Why don't you try to add a `filter` before `map`, just like `graph.tripletes.filter(triplet => triplet.attr == "condition").map(triplet => (triplet.srcAttr, triplet.dstAttr))`.

Comment: @kemiya Thank you! I know I can do it in that way. But the thing confusing me is that why these 2 codes above performs differently?

Comment: nope they are not the same. if is an expression which returns a value and the compiler seeks answer for the failure of if expression. but the case is like a filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO they are not the same.

The first function is a partial one, which means there is a possibility that the code will return Unit when the condition is not met.

The case function, on the other hand, matches all yout RDD rows (you have explicitly define RDD[string, string]). So it’s not a partial function like the first one.

Answer (score 2):

```
 if (triplet.attr == "condition"){
                (triplet.srcAttr, triplet.dstAttr)
 }
```

This block of code does not return a `(String, String)` type, it actually return `Unit` as the `else` branch is not defined.